# Does Storybook support async imports?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

My Storybook is not scaling well with large numbers of components, so I was hoping I could asynchronously register stories with Storybook

The syntax I'd *like* to use is something like this

```
const storyRoot = storiesOf(`${CORE_COMPONENTS}/Charts`, module);

(async () => {
    const SomeComponent = await import('../SomeComponent.tsx');

    storyRoot.add('Area Chart', () => <SomeComponent data={data} />);
})();
```

But it tries to render the Promise, so you get an invariant violation and it crashes before it gets a chance to resolve.

Comment: I had already posted issue regarding this - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6885

Answer (score 2):

You *can* lazy load components using the React Suspense API. However, it still gets loaded in the background. I'd prefer it only load the component when I click on the link in the sidebar. If anyone has a better solution, please post!

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const SomeComponent = lazy(() => import('./some-component'));
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';

storiesOf('SomeComponent', module)
    .add('story', () => (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <SomeComponent />
        </Suspense>
    ));
```